# how to use a document ready on a nested page in a full page site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready, fullpage.js

I have a site using **fullpage.js** but the principle is same for all the single page websites - I want to have `$(document).ready()` function on a 'nested' page as it's all on one page, naturally the document ready function would load before I want it to.

example:

```
<div id="page1"></div>
<div id="page2"></div>
<div id="page3">
     //when hit this page i would want the code to run
</div>
```

Is there a simple way of getting the document ready function equivalent for a nested page? I've found the [jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) plugin but as a lot of sites are using this single page style, are plugins the only solution or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex might help you

Comment: no, i assumed there would be a generic jquery way of doing the above, this would solve my problem for using fullpage.js so thanks! but is there an alternate for those not using it?

Comment: The alternate would be to write your own handler that does the same thing as the one in fullpage.js

Comment: Why should there be a generic jQuery way for handling events specific to a plugin?

Comment: no i mean, if you weren't using a specific plugin. Basically what alex said above, write the handler. The question was more generic than specific to my plugin, even though you solved my issue. (so feel free to put it an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic jQuery way of achieving this because all the functionality of fullpage.js isn't included in the jQuery core. And jQuery does not cover events fired by plugins.

In the docs of fullpage.js is a section about the [afterSlideLoad](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex) callback which gets "*fired once the slide of a section have been loaded, after the scrolling has ended*". There's also the [afterLoad](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) callback which will be "*fired once the sections have been loaded, after the scrolling has ended*". I don't know what fits your needs best. (Thanks to @Alvaro in the comments for the `afterLoad` callback)

Comment: He might want to use `afterLoad` which is for the vertical sections (`afterSlideLoad`) is for horizontal slides :) But yeah, you are in the good path. +1

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually never used fullpage.js, so I don't know the exact way of using it. I just googled :)

Comment: yeah it's fine. I just named it in case someone else reaches this answer trying to fire it on sections, which is what he seems to be looking for as well.